# python - Deleting User Messages using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing the bot on replit and for some reason all the other other posts on this topic date back to 17/18 so none of the older commands seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a certain message from a `ctx` or a `message` object, you use

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

or

```py
await message.delete()
```

If you want to delete all message from a certain user in one channel, use `purge`

```py
def check_for_user(check_message):
    return check_message.author == #the object of the user you want to purge messages from
await ctx.channel.purge(check=check_for_user)#could also be message.channel.purge... depends on where you are using it.
```

if you want to delete a list of messages, use `delete_messages()`:

```py
await ctx.channel.delete_messages(message_list_here)
```

---

### References

- [message.delete()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.delete)
- [channel.purge()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)
- [channel.delete_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages)